# Fix unclosed tags in html or parse with HTML parser for XSLT transformation

Tags: java, html, parsing, xslt, tags

I have some HTML code that is the result of an XSLT tranformation. (XML->HTML)

I want to run another XSLT transformation on the result HTML. (HTML->HTML)

My problem is that the first transformation may return unclosed tags like "`<img>`", which means that i can't parse the result html with DocumentBuilder because it uses SAXparser and of course my html file is not a valid xml in all cases. (I get an exception that the following XY tag must be closed.)

I guess there are two solutions.

1. Either fix the result HTML by closing the unclosed tags.
2. Use some kind of HTML parser to get a valid org.w3c.dom.Document and skip XML parsers like SAX.

I would really like to use mainly the same method I used for the first transformation, so I would prefer one of the solutions above the problem is that I can't find any obvious 3rd party jars that can help. (Though i looked.) So basically I would like to know what are my options here, are there any solutions to this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/ may help you

Comment: The HTML5 recommended approach is option 2. You are fortunate. There are lots of free HTML parsers in Java, and most will create a DOM compatible with org.w3c.dom.Document.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, I tested pretty much all of the suggestions, they all seem to be viable. After I ended up using the nu.validator.htmlparser.dom.HtmlDocumentBuilder class and it works like a charm. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [image][TagSoup - Just Keep On Truckin'](http://vrici.lojban.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/)[image]

You could use [**TagSoup**](http://vrici.lojban.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) to ensure that all of the documents are well-formed.

> ...a SAX-compliant parser written in Java
>   that, instead of parsing well-formed
>   or valid XML, parses HTML as it is
>   found in the wild: poor, nasty and
>   brutish, though quite often far from
>   short.
>
> TagSoup is designed for people
>   who have to process this stuff using
>   some semblance of a rational
>   application design.
>
> By providing a SAX
>   interface, it allows standard XML
>   tools to be applied to even the worst
>   HTML. TagSoup also includes a
>   command-line processor that reads HTML
>   files and can generate either clean
>   HTML or well-formed XML that is a
>   close approximation to XHTML.

If you are using Saxon, [you can make TagSoup your parser by adding the following option](http://vrici.lojban.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/tsaxon/):

> ...you can use the standard Saxon `-x
>   org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser` option,
>   after making sure that TagSoup is on
>   your Java classpath.

I have used this to parse and transform HTML documents in a single pass and have found that it works great. It will read the document as a well-formed XHTML document available to be manipulated and transformed through XML tools.

Also, [Taggle, a TagSoup in C++, available now](http://www.jezuk.co.uk/arabica/log?id=3591)

Comment: The link is down!

Answer (score 6):

What you need is `Jsoup : Java HTML Parser`. It has a functionality to output tidy HTML.

```
String html = "<p>The recurrence, in close succession <ul><li>list item 1</li><li>list item 2</li></ul> second part of thisssss";
String clean = Jsoup.clean(html, Whitelist.relaxed());
```

You can use other [Whitelist](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html) also.

Comment: That's OK, but it requires two parses and one serialization to get the data into the XSLT transformation. It should be possible to achieve the same with a single parse. Jsoup can probably do this but I don't know Jsoup, some other java HTML parsers certainly can.

Comment: @Alohci I think no matter what parser you use but you definitely need one parse to fix the `HTML`.

Comment: A good Java based HTML parser can go straight from badly formed markup to a org.w3c.dom.Document compatible DOM in a single parse (just like browsers do). The [validator.nu HTML parser](http://about.validator.nu/htmlparser/) is one that can, and I would expect most of the other popular ones can too.

Comment: @kaysush solution work for me but in  some case delete some table tag.

Comment: I am using Jsoup and I have <p> <img alt="" src="img64BEncode"></p>  an jsoup parse to this: <p> <img alt=""></p> Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tidy your XML. Try this library:

http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/